# how to eliminate maxim in a 2d vector c++

Tags: c++

Hi i need to eliminate an x from a 2d vector this is an example , C++

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

 x=9
```

cout

```
1 2
4 5
```

this is what i tried it doesn't work whenever iI put

```
1 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

it stops and I can't find the problem

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
  int v[100][100],i,j,x,m,n;
  int nv[100][100];  
  cout<<"linii:";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"coloane:";
  cin>>m;

  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Introduceti matricea"<<endl;
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
          cin>>v[i][j];
        }
    }
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"Matricea este"<<endl;
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
          cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    int k=0,l=0,q=0,t=0,p;
    cout<<"Introduceti X:";
    cin>>x;
   while(t == 0){
       p=0;
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
           if(v[i][j] == x){
                k=i;
                l=j;
                p++;
                q++;
                if(v[i][j]==v[i+1][j])
                {
                    k++;
                }
                    if(v[i][j]==v[i][j+1])
                    {
                        l++;
                    }

             }
        }
     }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
            if(i==k || j==l){}
            else if(i<k && j<l){
                nv[i][j]=v[i][j];
                }
            else if(i<k && j>l){
                nv[i][j-1]=v[i][j];
                }
            else if(i>k && j<l){
                nv[i-1][j]=v[i][j];
                }
            else {nv[i-1][j-1]=v[i][j];}
        }

    }
     for(i=1;i<=n-q;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=m-q;j++){
            v[i][j]=nv[i][j];

        }
    }
    if(p==1){
        t=1;
    }
}

    cout<<"matricea finala"<<endl;
    for(i=1;i<=n-q;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=m-q;j++){
            cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Do you want to remove line and column containing target value ?

Comment: Can you state simply what you're trying to do?  It's completely unclear.

Comment: Variable naming like `int v[100][100],i,j,x,m,n;` makes reading and debugging code much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` -- What compiler are you using?  Don't tell me it's something from the 1980's / early 1990's.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, I get the suspicion that what you wrote is overly complicating what you intend to do.  All you're doing is removing a certain column and row, and I doubt you need all that code to do such.  Also, if you want to actually remove a column and row, a vanilla 2D array isn't going to do that, as an array's size is fixed.

Comment: Remember that arrays in C/C++ are zero based, the index of `a[100]` goes from 0 to 99.

Comment: I use MinGWStudio, i want to remove a line and column containing a value , i know the value  from the beggining of the code. and whenever i meet the value  i have to eliminate the line and the column

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be

```
int main()
{
    int n, m, maxI = 0, maxJ = 0;
    cout << "linii:";
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> numbers(n);
    cout << "coloane:";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Introduceti matricea" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        numbers[i].resize(m);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> numbers[i][j];
            if (numbers[i][j] > numbers[maxI][maxJ])
            {
                maxI = i;
                maxJ = j;
            }
        }
    }

    numbers.erase(maxI + numbers.begin());
    cout << "matricea finala" << endl;
    for (auto& itr : numbers) {
        itr.erase(maxJ + itr.begin());
        for (const auto& itr2 : itr)
            cout << itr2 << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used **std::vector** in order to delete the max element.

Comment: If you want to store the array for future using, use vector instead fo map. I updated the answer.